# docker cannot start container ... cpu.shares: no such file or directory

Tags: docker, debian

When I try to run a docker image I get the following error:

```
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container {id}: 
[8] System error: open /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/init.scope/system.slice/docker-{id}.scope/cpu.shares: no such file or directory
```

`/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/` is mounted but there is no `system.slice` directory in `init.scope`

docker version:

```
Client version: 1.7.1
Client API version: 1.19
Go version (client): go1.4.2
Git commit (client): 786b29d
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.7.1
Server API version: 1.19
Go version (server): go1.4.2
Git commit (server): 786b29d
OS/Arch (server): linux/amd64
```

Kernel:

```
Linux christian-pc 4.1.0-2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.1.6-1 (2015-08-23) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

mounts (excerpt):

```
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=32,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext2 (rw,relatime)
/dev/mapper/christian--pc--vg-home on /home type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=814904k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: did you try with `sudo docker run ...`?

Comment: related issue on github: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/16256

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem, and I found your question and also https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=798778, "systemd 226's init.scope breaks docker.io 1.7.1~dfsg1-1."

Wherein Dmitry Smirnov says you can add `--exec-opt native.cgroupdriver=cgroupfs` to `DOCKER_OPTS` in `/etc/default/docker`.

Worked for me.

Comment: Indeed, it's systemd 226 breaking cfgroups, using the cgroupfs driver with docker fixes it. After changing the values you need to restart the docker daemon for it to work.

Comment: I had to add that to the invocation of docker in `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/docker.service`, but otherwise it worked.

Answer (score 7):

Changing `DOCKER_OPTS` to use cgroupfs  [as in Jared Jennings answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32878801/103081), may not be enough -- as there is another issue to check.

In a comment to [docker issue 9889](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/9889) "zepalmer" noted that the docker systemd entry could be configured
 in `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` not to use the `DOCKER_OPTS` in `/etc/default/docker`.  The consequence is that changing `/etc/default/docker` will be ineffective on how the daemon starts.

I found this issue was true in Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS:

Looking in 
`/lib/systemd/system/docker.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Docker Application Container Engine
Documentation=https://docs.docker.com
After=network.target docker.socket
Requires=docker.socket

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker -d -H fd://
MountFlags=slave
LimitNOFILE=1048576
LimitNPROC=1048576
LimitCORE=infinity

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

this is the same contents reported by zepalmer.

After changing the "ExecStart" line in the service section with the following:

```
EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/docker
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker -d $DOCKER_OPTS -H fd://
```

and including `--exec-opt native.cgroupdriver=cgroupfs` in `DOCKER_OPTS` in `/etc/default/docker`, docker seems to be working normally again.

Answer (score 0):

this save my day :)

1. sudo dnf config-manager \
   --add-repo \
   https://download.docker.com/linux/fedora/docker-ce.repo
2. sudo dnf -y install docker-ce
3. sudo groupadd docker && sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
4. sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
5. GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX add the parameter : systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0
6. sudo grub2-mkconfig reboot

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/33594